Unpivot data but keep order the same
So it flattens my data but changes the order. How do I keep it from changing the order of the header. In other words, I want each number in that column to be listed first before moving on to the next column.
Before unpivot:

After unpivot:

Changing the cells to "text" did not work

Post your input data as text table and then show your desired output.

Is the expected result h123;1564,h123;156,...h564;45678,h564;745546 i.e. the result of the formula=LET(data,Table1[#All],d,IF(data="","",data),v,DROP(d,1),a,TOCOL(IF(v="","",TAKE(d,1)),,1),FILTER(HSTACK(a,TOCOL(v,,1)),a<>""))?

Hi, I have posted an alternative without using Transpose feature of Power Query please share any feedback whether it works better than the earlier one or not. It might help us to know and learn something new!

Here is one way of doing this when using POWER QUERY:


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    DemotedHeaders = Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),
    Transpose = Table.Transpose(DemotedHeaders),
    UnpivotOtherCols = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Transpose, {"Column1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    RemovedCols= Table.RemoveColumns(UnpivotOtherCols,{"Attribute"})
in
    RemovedCols


And using Excel Formula could try:
=LET(
     α, Table1[#All],
     δ, DROP(α,1),
     HSTACK(
            TOCOL(IF(δ,TAKE(α,1),NA()),2,1),
            TOCOL(δ,1,1)))


Or, same as above but one extra step:
=LET(
     α, Table1[#All],
     δ, DROP(α,1),
     φ, HSTACK(TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(δ)), TAKE(α,1)),,1),TOCOL(δ,,1)),
     FILTER(φ, TAKE(φ,,-1)>0))


So, what I have realized using Transpose in Power Query is not an healthy option or a better idea, as it will be slower to process when working on a large data scale. Here is a way which will be much quicker and efficient way to get the desired output so that one can work smoothly.


Better Option:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Cols = Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    ToLists = List.Transform(Table.ToColumns(Source), each List.RemoveNulls(_)),
    PackingTogether = Table.FromColumns({Cols}&{ToLists}, {"Header1","Header2"}),
    ExpandedCols = Table.ExpandListColumn(PackingTogether, "Header2")
in
    ExpandedCols


NOTE: Suggested and recommended not to use the transpose feature in Power Query for this particular use case, instead use the better option alternative.

